# My bullet changes the velocity depending on where I click

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, mouse, shooter

I want to build a little 2D-Sidescrolling shooter and I'm now at the shooting script.

I already figured out how to shoot a bullet towards my mouse pointer. I got something like this :

```
Vector3 shootDirection;
        shootDirection = Input.mousePosition;
        shootDirection.z = 0.0f;
        shootDirection = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (shootDirection);
        shootDirection = shootDirection - transform.position;

        shootDirection.Normalize ();

        Rigidbody2D bulletInstance = Instantiate (rocket, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as Rigidbody2D;
        bulletInstance.velocity = new Vector2 (shootDirection.x * speed, shootDirection.y * speed);
```

Now obviously the bullet goes faster if my Direction coordinates are big and slower if they are smaller. Have you some better code for me or how can I fix that issue?

I added now some loop like this, which brings a horrible performance, but kinda works out for the problem, but I'm still looking for a better solution.

```
while (((shootDirection.x * speed) + (shootDirection.y * speed)) < 20) {
            speed += 0.1f;
        }
```

So the loop makes sure that the overall speed is always almost the same, but this solution ends in an infinity loop if the values get too small.

Comment: Is `transform.position` also fixed at 0.0f on the Z axis? If not, this will affect the Normalize function.

Comment: Mhm I don't know about that, but how would that affect the bullet? Can I see that visualy?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed that and I don't think that it changed anything.

Comment: "Now obviously the bullet goes faster if my Direction coordinates are big and slower if they are smaller." Are you sure? Why is it that obvious? Your call to `shootDirection.Normalize();` should take care of this, shouldn't it?

Comment: Why should that take care of the problem? If I shoot close to my character it says something like 0.1 * speed, which is obviously less then something like 0.9 * speed

Comment: `Normalize` makes everything the same length, so after that points far away and close by have the same "size".  At that point, you should just be able to do `shootDirection *  20.0` (instead of your loop - speed will always be 20) to get the actual distance traveled for a projectile per unit time.  If you're ignoring `z`, though, why aren't you using a 2D vector?

Comment: Does calling normalize actually normalize the vector or does it return a normalized vector? I'm betting it could be the second behavior and that your vector isn't getting normalized because you are ignoring the return value.

Comment: I'm actually pretty new to Unity and even more new to 2D, I have no idea what I'm doing :D, but I will try it with a 2D-Vector thanks. So I had these values in a Debug.Log, so I could see, that the values changed between 0.0 and 0.9 from how far I've clicked. I hope I get this fixed with 2D-Vector

Comment: So the Normalize function has void as return, but I would have to create a new variable if I would use shootingDirection.normalized, this function has a return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the 2D-Vector solved the problem, I don't know why, because I think it should do the same but this is my code now and it's working

```
        Vector2 target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
        Vector2 myPos = new Vector2 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
        Vector2 direction = target - myPos;
        direction.Normalize ();
        Rigidbody2D projectile = Instantiate (rocket, myPos, Quaternion.identity) as Rigidbody2D;
        projectile.velocity = direction * speed;
```